# Rails nested attributes giving error: undefined method `build_priority'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-forms, has-many

All day but can't find simple problem. Why my nested attribute is not working with this association?

```
Here is error: NoMethodError (undefined method `build_priority' for
#<Audit:0x134234jnjn2j>):   app/controllers/audits_controller.rb:43:in `new'
```

audits_controller.rb

```
 def new
    @audit = Audit.new
    @audit.build_priority 
 end
```

audit.rb model

```
  has_many :priorities, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :priorities, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
```

priority.rb model

```
class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :audit
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :audit, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

Comment: did the given answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
 def new
    @audit = Audit.new
    @audit.priorities.build
 end
```

models:-

```
class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :priorities, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :priorities, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

end

class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :audit
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :audit, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

Comment: now its giving: "Association :priority not found". @Gabbar

Comment: do you have `priority_id` field in `Audit` model? and how is your `Audit` and `Priority` model associated?

Comment: Audit has_many priorities so there is no "priority_id" needed. But each Priority has "audit_id". You can see associations in question.

Comment: @DanielsV see the changes made recently and restart your server again and try

Comment: @DanielsV let me know for further guidance. if it helped feel free to accept upvote answer

Comment: @Gabber answer didn't work but there was totally different problem, which is solved and didn't even involve files I presented in question. Sorry. I probably will close this question. Thanks for answer!